# Error with docker CMD

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a docker image but I am getting an error:

> /bin/sh: /tmp/test.sh && java -jar /tmp/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar &> /tmp/artifacts/selenium.log.txt: No such file or directory

Here is the build of the image:

```
FROM image:latest
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/artifacts/Logs && \
    mkdir -p /tmp/artifacts/Screenshots
CMD "/bin/sh /tmp/test.sh && /usr/bin/java -jar /tmp/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar &> /tmp/artifacts/selenium.log.txt &"
```

When running the image with command /bin/sh and executing the command manually there is no error.

Comment: the error message is `No such file or directory` so you see what the problem is. You should post your Dockerfile

Comment: That is already the Dockerfile. The files on CMD are all existing.

Comment: you need a `ADD` or `COPY`  to get test.sh

Comment: test.sh exists in your host, but a docker container is isolated from the host, you need to copy all what is needed, the .sh, the .jar...

Comment: It exist when running the image.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it the reason here is that I am using multiple commands.
I have solved this by using supervisor which I used to run the commands.